# Scanf value of a 2+ digit char?

Tags: c

```
    int main(){
  char c;
  scanf("%c", &c);
  printf("%d\n", c);
}
```

Suppose the user enters `71` and hits enter.

Why doesn't `c` become`71`, why does it only read the `7` and not the `1`?

Comment: Do you know what `char` is? How can single variable contain two values?

Comment: @EugeneSh., yes a character

Comment: And how can it contain two characters then?

Comment: @EugeneSh., then if an integer is only 4 bytes, how can I scan a 5 digit integer?

Comment: @Onedayanam - because 2 to the power of 32 is more than 10 to the power of 6.

Comment: I give up, sorry...

Comment: When you scan `7` as `char`, it takes value of the _character_ `7` in your local encoding. Eg, this is probably ASCII, in which case your `char` takes the value `0x37=55`. It doesn't take the value `7`, because you're using it as a _character_, not an 8-bit integer. When you scan `7` as an integer, it takes the value `7`. These things are not alike.

Comment: @Onedayanam that's rude. I've made a fair effort, but it's hard to describe how basic this misunderstanding is. You're mixing up the terms _character_, _byte_ and _digit_ without understanding how they differ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing some key distinctions.

The `scanf` function takes as input a string of characters. Each character is an 8-bit integer representing one of:

- a printable glyph such as '7', or '1', or 'G'
- a control character such as newline ('\n') or bel ('\a')
- the nul terminator (`\0`) which is used to mark the end of a string of characters.

(I'm assuming ASCII for simplicity, other encodings are available).

The printable characters appear on your screen as letters, numbers or symbols when you print them. The control characters control what your terminal/display device does (newline makes it move the notional cursor to the next line, and bel makes some terminals emit an audible beep).

---

What `scanf` does with this string of input characters is controlled by the format string:

- `%c` reads incoming characters *without conversion* into `char` values.
- `%d` converts a sequence of characters in the range '0'..'9' (that is, values 0x30..0x39) into an integer.

So, when the character '7' is scanned as a character with `%c`, it gives the value 0x37 (decimal 55) still assuming ASCII.
When the same character is scanned as an integer with `%d`, it takes the value 7.

If you want to scan the string "71", as an integer value, use `%d` (or `%hhd` if for some reason you really want to store it in a char).

---

Now, finally, we can address this comment:

> ... if an integer is only 4 bytes, how can I scan a 5 digit integer?

Let's consider the string literal "12345", which is stored in memory as

```
const char literal[6] = {0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x00};
```

If you scan this  with `%d`, then those 5 non-nul bytes will be converted as a base-10 integer into the value 12345.

However, if you scan the same string with `%5c`, you'll populate a 5-char buffer with the values `{0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35}`. If you try using plain `%c` it will, of course, read only the first character, which is 0x31.

Answer (score 1):

'7' is a character and '1' is a character. The character 'G' has a decimal value of 71. Type 'G' and you'll get 71. If you want to scan for a number you could:

```
int i;
scanf("%d", &i);
printf("Value %d = char(%c)", i, (char)i);
```

Once the system scanf the '7' it had the one character it was waiting for and stops listening - your '1' hasn't been "scanned" in yet!

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
scanf ("%c", &c);
```

means "read one *byte* from standard input and place it into the variable `c`". No conversion is done. In your example, the byte is `'7'`, which, assuming that the program runs in a locale which uses ASCII (or a superset, such as UTF-8) character encoding, is the same as `'\x37'`, or `55`. Note that the value assigned to `c` depends on the character encoding used by the current locale.

By comparison, a statement such as

```
scanf ("%d", &i);
```

means "read one or more *characters* representing decimal digits from standard input, convert those decimal digits into an integer value, and store that value in the variable `i`". Note that the value assigned to the variable `i` does not depend on the character encoding used by the current locale, provided of course that standard input uses the encoding expected by the program.